# OpenSSL trouble with Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, openssl, ruby-1.9.3, ubuntu-12.04

I am having a semi-serious problem with OpenSSL 1.0.1 + Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

All rubies are installed with rvm

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

endpoint = "https://secure.mmoagateway.com/api/transact.php"
RUBY_184_POST_HEADERS = { "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
body = "orderid=ae5dd847d9f31209cbffeeea076ed966&orderdescription=Active+Merchant+Remote+Test+Purchase&ccnumber=4111111111111111&ccexp=0913&cvv=123&company=Widgets+Inc&address1=1234+My+Street&address2=Apt+1&city=Ottawa&state=ON&zip=K1C2N6&country=CA&phone=%28555%29555-5555&firstname=&lastname=&email=&amount=1.00&type=auth&username=demo&password=password"
headers = {}

endpoint     = endpoint.is_a?(URI) ? endpoint : URI.parse(endpoint)

http = Net::HTTP.new(endpoint.host, endpoint.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
http.set_debug_output(STDOUT)

result = http.post(endpoint.request_uri, body, RUBY_184_POST_HEADERS.merge(headers))
puts(result)
```

On Ubuntu 12.04 + Ruby 1.9.3 + Openss 1.0.1 I get the following output:

```
% ruby test.rb 
opening connection to secure.mmoagateway.com...
opened
Conn close because of connect error Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1307:in `send_entity'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1096:in `post'
        from test.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

With Ruby 1.8.7 I get the correct output:

```
$ ruby test.rb
opening connection to secure.mmoagateway.com...
opened
<- "POST /api/transact.php HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 347\r\nHost: secure.mmoagateway.com\r\n\r\n"
<- "orderid=ae5dd847d9f31209cbffeeea076ed966&orderdescription=Active+Merchant+Remote+Test+Purchase&ccnumber=4111111111111111&ccexp=0913&cvv=123&company=Widgets+Inc&address1=1234+My+Street&address2=Apt+1&city=Ottawa&state=ON&zip=K1C2N6&country=CA&phone=%28555%29555-5555&firstname=&lastname=&email=&amount=1.00&type=auth&username=demo&password=password"
-> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
-> "Date: Wed, 04 Jul 2012 01:26:35 GMT\r\n"
-> "Server: Apache\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 240\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 240 bytes...
-> "response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=1648894346&avsresponse=N&cvvresponse=N&orderid=ae5dd847d9f31209cbffeeea076ed966&type=auth&response_code=100&merchant_defined_field_6=&merchant_defined_field_7=&customer_vault_id="
read 240 bytes
Conn close
#<Net::HTTPOK:0xb74175c8>
response=1&responsetext=SUCCESS&authcode=123456&transactionid=1648894346&avsresponse=N&cvvresponse=N&orderid=ae5dd847d9f31209cbffeeea076ed966&type=auth&response_code=100&merchant_defined_field_6=&merchant_defined_field_7=&customer_vault_id=
```

I have the same issue in arch with 1.9.3 and 1.0.1.

If I install 1.0.0e from oneiric on my 12.04 system it also works fine with ruby 1.9.3

I think this may be related to ubuntu bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371

Although I downloaded the packages from Debian where they said it was fixed and had no luck.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Comment: I have no fix, only some data points: The problem reproduces on my machine (Debian testing, Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.3, openssl 1.0.1b-1).  The problem does not reproduce if I try connecting to a different https host.  Oh, and I'm not sure that the symptoms in that bug report match your symptoms very well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem connecting to an authorization gateway. In the end I was able to connect by forcing sslv3

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true if @is_https
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if @is_https
http.ssl_version = :SSLv3
```

Comment: It's been a while since I have checked this post but. YES! this works for me. Seems like it should be able to negotiate this on it's own but this will solve my problem.

Comment: Here is a solution that fixes this problem without disabling certificate verification

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem... [here](http://blog.marc-seeger.de/2012/06/22/ruby-openssl-and-econnreset/) is information, that `rvm pkg install openssl` and `rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p194 --with-openssl-dir=~/.rvm/usr` solves the problem, but it doesn't help me

Comment: Yeah, that only worked for me after an major version OSX upgrade and the connected problems with brew/macports/... In this case it might help reinstalling ruby though. Maybe he updated openssl after compiling ruby 1.9

Comment: still doesn't work for me. I have latest 1.0.1 on base linux system, also rvm openssl is exactly the same, I tried all possible solution, didn't solve for me... any idea?

Comment: `--with-openssl-dir=...` isn't a valid configure option for 1.9.3: `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-openssl-dir`