# openssl 1.0.1 with ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

i keep getting an error message below.

> Errno::ECONNRESET in CybozuliveController#index
>
> Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

and of course ive tried the below

> rvm pkg install openssl
>
> rvm remove 1.9.3
>
> rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-gcc=clang

anyone know how to get openssl 1.0.0 ? :s

in my old mac, ruby 1.9.3 and openssl 1.0.0 worked so if i could get openssl 1.0.0,

i think ill be fine

Answer (score 0):

this could be related to `clang`, Ruby is not guaranted to always work with it, try installing `gcc-4.2`.

at first make sure you run the new stable from RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

read:

```
rvm requirements
```

for how to install `gcc-4.2`, and reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

it will use the rvm installed openssl (it does it autmaticaly, no need to give `--with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr`), not specifying `--with-gcc=` will allow RVM to select `gcc-4.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the same issue i was here: [OpenSSL trouble with Ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321403/openssl-trouble-with-ruby-1-9-3/13811555#13811555)

I think Open SSL 1.0.1 caused some problems negotiating the ssl version to use with some older/non-standard servers. Read the answer in that question to see how to force it.