# How do I post JSON via HTTP in Ruby after conversion from Python?

Tags: python, ruby, json

I yield - I've tried for hours to crack this nut but can't figure it out.  I'm too new to Ruby (and have no Python background!) to translate this and then post my JSON data to a site that requires user/pass, and then get the response data.

This is the Python code:

```
r = requests.post('https://keychain.oneid.com/validate/', json.dumps(data), auth=('username', 'password'))
r.json()
```

where `data` is:

```
{"some" => "data", "fun" => "times"}
```

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of this code in Ruby for use with a Rails application, but between figuring out how the Python `requests.post()` function operates and then writing the Ruby code for POST and GET, I've become totally lost.

I tried Net::HTTP but I'm not clear if I should be putting the username/pass in the body or use the `basic_auth` method -- `basic_auth` seems to only work inside `Net::HTTP.get` ... and Net::HTTP doesn't seem to easily handle JSON, but again, I could be totally out to lunch at this point.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem or just use `Net::HTTP`.

Ruby code(version 1.9.3):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('https://keychain.oneid.com/validate/')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path
# ruby 2.0: req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri
req.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
req.body = {:some => 'data', :fun => 'times'}.to_json

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) do |http|
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  http.ssl_version = :SSLv3
  http.request req
end

puts res.body
# => {"errorcode": -99, "error": "Invalid API credentials. Please verify and try again"}

json = JSON.parse res.body
puts json['errorcode']
# => -99
```

Comment: Two things -1) Where is the JSON data sent? 2) Mine just errors out with "rrno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect" ... any ideas?

Comment: 1) Add JSON data: req.body = {:some => 'data', :fun => 'times'}.to_json 2) Maybe it's an OpenSSL problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321403/openssl-trouble-with-ruby-1-9-3

Comment: Thank you very much, working like a charm.  If anyone else hits the OpenSSL problem, this resource was the best and solved my issue: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: @user2203324 Oh yeah! My first answer, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend taking a look at the [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem. It makes it easy to deal with GET/POST, plus all the rest of the REST calls. It also has an IRB-based shell called `restclient` available from the command-line, making it easier to experiment with your connection settings.

From the documentation:

```
RestClient.post "http://example.com/resource", { 'x' => 1 }.to_json, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

Looking at it you can see similarities with the Python code.

You can add the authentication info to the hash:

```
require 'restclient'
require 'json'
require 'base64'

RestClient.post(
  'https://keychain.oneid.com/validate/',
  {
    :authentication => 'Basic ' + Base64.encode64(name + ':' + password),
    'some' => 'data',
    'fun' => 'times'
  }.to_json,
  :content_type => :json,
  :accept => :json
)
```

Alternately, you could use the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem. Curb used libcurl, which is an industry standard tool for web connectivity. The documentation shows several ways to send POST requests.